# Left Join My SQL Query with spesific value

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

**divisions**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Division A |
| 2 | Division B |
| 3 | Division C |
| 4 | Division D |
| 5 | Division E |

**employees**

| id | division_id | is_structural | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | Employee A |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | Employee B |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | Employee C |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | Employee D |
| 5 | 3 | 0 | Employee E |

and i want to divisions table left join to employee with is_structural column in employees table must have value is 1 on every divisions and if is not exists return null, like this

| a.id | a.name | b.id | b.is_structural | b.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Division A | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | Division D | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | Division E | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Division B | 3 | 1 | Employee C |
| 3 | Division C | 4 | 1 | Employee D |
| 3 | Division C | 5 | 1 | Employee E |
| 1 | Division A | 1 | 0 | Employee A |
| 1 | Division A | 2 | 0 | Employee B |

What is mysql queries?

- **Current queries**

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    b.id,
    b.is_structural,
    b.name
FROM 
    divisions a
    LEFT JOIN (employees b) ON (b.division_id = a.id)
```

Comment: I am unclear how you get to your result specifically where do the last 2 rows come from? I thought they were supposed to be null according to the wording.

Comment: You need 2 queries. First query produces first 3 rows (use WHERE NOT EXISTS), second query produces last 5 rows (common INNER JOIN). And UNION ALL.

Comment: And why does is_structure for employee 3 changed to 1 for division 3 and why is division 3 included at all in result?

Comment: so I mean, each division must be filled by 1 employee with the position of division head. and divisions that do not have division heads (null) are at the forefront, both divisions with division heads, then ordinary employees

Comment: Help me out here - how do establish division head?

Comment: is_structural on employees table is head i mean

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    b.id,
    b.is_structural,
    b.name
FROM 
    divisions a
    LEFT JOIN employees b ON  b.division_id = a.id and b.is_structural = 1
```